# What is optimizer.weights in tf.keras.optimizer('fo')?

Tags: tensorflow, keras

It sounds like it gives a list of variables that relate to the way that optimizer works and I shouldn't worry about that. **But**, I have suspicions that it also relates to the things I'm trying to minimize and the variables I'm using for that. Is that true? In other words, is it safe to use just one optimizer in my NN that has multiple objective functions? **Or should I instantiate a separate optimizer for each one?**

Answer (score 1):

Generally, you stick to one optimizer.

You add up all your losses.

```
total_loss = loss1+loss2+lossN
```

If you think that one loss is more than the other you can weight them against each other:

```
total_loss = 0.01*unimportant+regular+10.0*low_rare_and_important
```

Using multiple optimizers is not intended. It might lead to higher memory consumption. Although, you are not strictly prohibited from having more than one.

Comment: That is clear. But, say that I decided to optimize each loss separately. Is it safe to use the same optimizer object for all of them?

Comment: Technicly, optimizer will simply get a derivative of your loss against trainable parameters. So, it should be fine

Comment: On the second thought, if it is any sort of accelerated optimizer than it would be inconsistent, regardless of whether you use a single one or multiple optimizers